# Chrome Rendering Bug

Tags: support, google-chrome, page-rendering

There seems to be a weird rendering bug on Google Chrome 20 Stable.

> [image: Chrome 20 Stable Rendering Bug]

For some reason, everything was fine on the Developer channel but not the Stable channel. =/ And this applies to every beta site.

---

**Update:** I think it had something to do with the default font. Because I changed the default font from *Canterall* to *Droid Sans* and it was corrected.

Comment: No repro with Chrome 20.0.1132.47 m (Win7) on any beta site (including Raspberry Pi). Make sure to turn off any funky extensions.

Comment: It seems to be some weird thing with the fault. I'm assuming that the font width is different and that is forcing it to be shifted down?

Comment: Same here. I'm on Arch Linux and haven't got Arial installed. I think it's our problem rather than SOs.